# SQL Grouping by Like using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with unique names and a combination of those same names separated by commas in the same field as below:

```
Bill
Mark
Steve
Bill, Mark
Mark, Steve
Bill,Mark, Steve
```

I would like to Group the names not separated by a comma for a count of those where the name exists such as:

```
Bill 3
Mark 4
Steve 3
```

In the future someone may add another name to the table so I can't use a Case statement with static names. I would like something like this:

```
SELECT
   Name
FROM
   My_Table
Group By
   Name Like (SELECT Name FROM My_Table Where Name Not Like '%,%')
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you in any position to change strategies entirely? This table should be rethought into two tables - one which defines names, and another which defines a many-to-many relationship between names. What you have will cause you lots of headaches going forward (you're experiencing one now..)

Comment: Sadly I am not. This table is auto-generated and given to me as is. I am trying to sort it out for a report where the user can select their name from the dropdown which is created using the (Select Name From My_Table where Name not like '%,%') query. I give a count on this summary which then drills down but because the summary doesn't include all "likes" the numbers are different.

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using? Some of them have facilities for dealing with CSV columns, but they're all different and none is particularly great.

Comment: Sorry about that. Using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an instance of SQLServer to test this out, but an approach that may work is selecting only the simple-name records and then a nested SELECT expression that will count all records with that name.  Something like this:

```
 SELECT 
   Name, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable Y2 WHERE Name LIKE ('%' + Y1.Name + '%'))
   FROM YourTable Y1 WHERE NAME NOT LIKE '%,%'
```

It will fail, of course, on nested names.  (Bob and Bobby, if they're different people, for instance).  A more robust approach would require removing all the spaces from around commas and building out the LIKE expression into three LIKEs ORed together.  If you can't create a LIKE value in-line the way I did, you can substitute whatever the SQLServer function for location-within-string is.

But, honestly, I'd project a temporary normalized table and base your report off that.

Comment: Thanks so much Larry, this ended up working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select N.Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT Name
  FROM My_Table
  WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%,%'
) Names N
JOIN My_Table MT
ON (MT.Name LIKE '%' + N.Name  + ',%' OR MT.Name LIKE '%,' + N.Name + '%' OR MT.Name = N.Name)
GROUP BY N.Name
```

Comment: Thank you Sam. This seems to be returning a much larger count than I anticipated (I got 102,000 results for one of the names when I expected 350). I will continue to play with it though as it looks promising and if the result is correct will certainly mark this as the answer.

Comment: Changed it slightly to incorporate something in Larry's answer - the LIKE statements were not counting the base case (name of 'Bob') and would have included nested names ('Bobby' for 'Bob')

Comment: Certainly no reason to downvote. In attempting to keep the information semi-private I'm sure I've left out important information that can influence my results through no fault of Sams. I appreciate the effort of anyone willing to help a SLQ noob like myself.